# Error when trying to open a file for reading (with special character) in python

Tags: python, file, text

I getting an error when I'm trying to open a file for reading in Python.
Some one can help please? I read that it's might related to the usage of special character like "_" , 
but it's funny that in some other part of my code I'm doing the same thing (with different string variable) and it's work....

if you look at the error message, in the end of the path..you can see addition of "\n"
the path is changing from some reason ...
why does it's happening?

thanks in advance,
eliran

```
msgs_file = open("C:\\Users\\"+user+"\\Documents\\Notifications\\messages\\msg_"+track_time_stamp+".text","r", encoding="utf-8")           
lines = msgs_file.readlines()
matching_msg = lines[0]                                                                                                                                               
msgs_file.close()
```

error msg:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\eliran\\Documents\\Notifications\\messages\\msg_15.06.2020_18.00\n.text'
```

Comment: Are you asking why there's a \n in the filename? It's because the variable track_time_stamp contains that character. Yoy may want to 'clean' it by running strip.

Comment: exactly !! you're right.. how can i clean it? I was trying by using track_time_stamp.strip("\n")

Comment: strip is the right way to go. Do: track_time_stamp = track_time_stamp.strip("\n")

Comment: sorry my mistakes. it's works perfect ! thanks a lot !!

Comment: Yea... or just track_time_stamp = track_time_stamp.rstrip()

Answer (score 0):

try encoding="latin-1" instead of UTF-8